# LD_PRELOAD trouble

Tags: opengl, static, hook, shared, ld-preload

I've been hooking some methods within the OpenGL interface to add some additional functionality (in this case, convert OpenGL to a TCP/UDP protocol).

I've been using a simple shared library which I've built with GCC along with LD_Preload to modify the existing functions. This technique seems to be working great for some methods, and I have working versions for methods like dlsym and glBegin.

However, I'm having trouble hooking some of the glx functions, such as `glXSwapBuffers` and `glXMakeCurrent`.

Can anyone shed some light onto why I can hook the regular openGL methods but not glx?

Comment: Just to clarify: the `glX` functions are not part of `OpenGL`. They are part of an [X11 extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLX), which also defines additional wire (command) protocols for the X client/server model.

Answer (score 0):

> (in this case, convert OpenGL to a TCP/UDP protocol).

May I ask why? By using X11/GLX OpenGL (until version 2.1, unfortunately there no GLX for OpenGL-3 and later yet) is already network transparent. No extra work is required.

Why do you think OpenGL-1.1 to OpenGL-2.1 did have functions

```
glDisableClientState
 glEnableClientState
         ^^^^^^
```